# Firebird Сборка проекта из исходников

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, firebird, makefile

Добрый день, уже несколько дней пытаюсь собрать проект Firebird из исходников, беру от сюда:

https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/firebird/tree/B3_0_Release

инструкция:

https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/building-the-code/

Пробовал так же мастер версию, не помогло. К сему посланию прилагаю логи из консоли и вывод ошибок самой консоли. Быть может у вас есть собранный проект, буду бесконечно признателен! установленные VS: 2008, 2015 Prof, 2017 Prof

Comment: файлы тут:
https://yadi.sk/d/tNOd6-YY3UbneF
 
asd - файл лога

Comment: там же указан багтрекер: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/

Comment: К сожалению они мне так и не ответили, да и нет смысла, причина в моём "невеждестве"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема оказалась в неправильных окончаниях. Загрузка исходников с GIT через Торторис решила мою проблему.